# React: how to duplicate a child component by pressing a button?

Tags: reactjs, clone

I'm trying to clone a child component which represents an image in a parent gallery component.
The main idea is duplicating the image by pressing on a button which inside it.

The problem is that i cant find a way to inform the parent component on duplicating a specific image.
I was trying to send a callback method as a 'props' but it didn't work so well

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tag: PropTypes.string  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      galleryWidth: this.getGalleryWidth()
    };

  }

  getGalleryWidth(){
    try {
      return document.body.clientWidth;
    } catch (e) {
      return 1000;
    }
  }

  getImages(tag) {
    const getImagesUrl = `services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=522c1f9009ca3609bcbaf08545f067ad&tags=${tag}&tag_mode=any&per_page=100&format=json&safe_search=1&nojsoncallback=1`;
    const baseUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/';
    axios({
      url: getImagesUrl,
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
        if (
          res &&
          res.photos &&
          res.photos.photo &&
          res.photos.photo.length > 0
        ) {
          this.setState({images: res.photos.photo});
        }
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages(this.props.tag);
    this.setState({
      galleryWidth: document.body.clientWidth
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.getImages(props.tag);
  }


  clone(img){
    this.setState({images:[img]});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="gallery-root">
        {this.state.images.map(dto => {
           return <Image key={'image-' + dto.id} dto={dto} callBack={this.clone.bind(this)} galleryWidth={this.state.galleryWidth} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

and this is the Image component :

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dto: PropTypes.object,
    galleryWidth: PropTypes.number

  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.calcImageSize = this.calcImageSize.bind(this);
    this.onFilter = this.onFilter.bind(this);
    this.onExpand=this.onExpand.bind(this);
    this.closeLightBox=this.closeLightBox.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      size: 200,
      filterType:'none',
      isExpand:false,
      img:props.dto
    };
  }

  calcImageSize() {
    const {galleryWidth} = this.props;
    const targetSize = 200;
    const imagesPerRow = Math.round(galleryWidth / targetSize);
    const size = (galleryWidth / imagesPerRow);

    this.setState({
      size:size,
      isExpand:false
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.calcImageSize();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.getImages(props.tag);
  }

  urlFromDto(dto) {
    return `https://farm${dto.farm}.staticflickr.com/${dto.server}/${dto.id}_${dto.secret}.jpg`;
  }

  onClone(){
    this.props.callBack([this.props.dto]);
  }


  render() {
    return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <div
        className="image-root"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px',
          filter : this.state.filterType
        }}
        >
        <div>
          <a onClick={this.onClone.bind(this)}><FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="clone" title="clone"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Image;
```

---

I think the problem is with the data passed to the parent? The result that was shown is an object with no image.

I would really appreciate your help.
thanks

Comment: I think you have a problem with your `clone(img)`. I have posted a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

In Parent Component

```
 clone(img){
    this.setState({images:[img]});
  }
```

Can be updated to

```
 clone(img){
    this.setState(
         (prevState)=>{
                prevState.images.push(img);
                return {images:prevState.images}
         }
    );
  }
```

Then in the child component

Update onClone function to

```
  onClone(){
    this.props.callBack(this.props.dto);
  }
```

probably you have messed with the `this.state.images` array

Comment: well, I tried to print the size of the images array... it's getting bigger after each click but still not showing any changes in the gallery.

Comment: I have tried it with a rough example check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/1vrp55vj84 Hope it helps